# Image positioning seems strange

Tags: html, css

When I insert an image into my HTML it gets positioned in the lower left corner for some reason. Even if I set position to center; it stays in that strange position. What could be causing this?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Animation Verkefni</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </header>

    <body>
    <div class="doge1">
        <p>
        Transitions in CSS are applied to an element and specify that when a property changes it should do so gradually over a period of time. Animations are different. When applied, they just run and do their thing. They offer more fine-grained control as you can control different stops of the animations.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="doge2">
        <img src="spengbab.jpg">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
background-color:gray;
}

p {
font-size:50px;
margin-left:500px;
margin-right:500px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:250px;
font-family:impact;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {opacity:1;}
25%  {opacity:2;}
50%  {opacity:3;}
75%  {opacity:4;}
100% {opacity:10;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari og Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:1;}
25%  {opacity:2;}
50%  {opacity:3;}
75%  {opacity:4;}
100% {opacity:10;}
}
.doge2 {
position:fixed center;
top:20px;
}

.doge1:hover
{
animation-name: myfirst;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari og Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name: myfirst;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `position: fixed center;` doesn't exist ;) You mixed up `background` properties.

Comment: opacity values from 0 to 1.

Comment: @RupamDatta yeah that too.

Comment: `position: fixed center;` is there something like that? i dont think..

Comment: Ok...give image `width` and `height` and center it like this e.g. `.doge2 img { position: fixed; width: 200px; height: 200px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -100px; }`.

Comment: are you looking to align the image at the center where it is placed or to center it in a fixed position?? vertically/horizontally??

Comment: Absolutely in the center of my screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `position:fixed;` & `text-align:center;`

Like this:

```
.doge2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Good for horizontal align.

Comment: @mdesdev you want to position it vertically center??

Comment: I didn't ask the question :) I gave my answer for centering fixed positioned elements above in comments.

Comment: This helps, but yes, as mdesdev pointed out, I indeed want it absolutely centered in the middle of the screen, which means I need it vertically centered too.

Comment: @mdesdev sorry bro! i didnt realized it was you, i thought the comment was from the post owner :)

Comment: @user3066560 could you make a fiddle with current status??

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

to keep image at center position.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.